# Prolog backtracks and executes other statements too

Tags: prolog, logic, predicate

Assume you have following facts:

```
sister(susan, jane).
sister(karren,holtby).
parent_of(susan,karren).
parent_of(susan,holtby).
```

And the following definitions:

```
sibling(X, Y) :-
      sister(X, Y).

sibling(X, Y) :-
      parent_of(Z, X), parent_of(Z, Y).
```

Is there any reason why the goal `sibling(susan, jane)` gives a true then a false. Are both definitions used?

Is there a way to only check all the definitions for a true only and output true if so?

Comment: When I try `sister(susan, jane).` with your code, I just get "true". Did you mean `sibling(susan, jane).`? If so, that will yield "true" but then there's a choice point to check for more solutions. If you say, "check for more" by pressing `;` then it comes back "false" because there aren't any more solutions.

Comment: Yes sorry i had a typo there. It should be sibling(susan, jane). I understand the backtracking but is there any way to prevent it?

Comment: You could add a cut: `sibling(X, Y) :- sister(X, Y), !.` That says if `X` and `Y` are sisters, then they are siblings and you don't want to look for any more siblings between `X` and `Y`. But that could eliminate solutions you want in other cases. Why do you want to get rid of the backtrack? It's a normal part of how Prolog works.

Comment: Just made the output look more neater. Thanks for the solution works perfectly now

Comment: You just have to be careful not to sacrifice valid solutions for other queries in order to get "neater" output for this one. :)

Answer (score 0):

Prolog is a tree based language. Let's establish a knowledge base

```
male(mark).
female(mary).
female(beth).
brother(mark, mary). %mark is the brother of mary
brother(mark, beth).

%define sister
sister(X,Y) :-
  female(X),
  male(Y),
  brother(Y,X).
```

In this case the clause sister would be evaluated as such:

- Bind mary to X
- Bind mark to Y
- Check knowledge base for brother(mark, mary)
- Return true if this is found
- Bind beth to X
- Bind mark to Y
- Check knowledge base for brother(mark, beth)
- return true if this is found
- no other bindings exist, so return false

In Prolog all possibilities are tried. It will return all true cases until it can't find one, then it will automatically return false (i.e. Nothing can satisfy this). This is the strength and confusion with prolog.